# differences between PHP 5.2 and 5.4 / Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have following code:

```
  Line 27:  while($tab[array_keys($tab)[$a]] > 0)
```

It works on PHP 5.4 but doesn't work on 5.2.
I'm getting this error code:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ']' in path/to/script on line 27
```

Process finished with exit code 255 at 14:39:03.

What should I do ?

I have no idea :(

**SOLVED**
Solution below

Comment: Array dereferencing was introduced in PHP 5.4; you really shouldn't still be running PHP 5.2 anyway

Comment: I know, but I take part in competition. They have online compiler and only PHP 5.2 :) I'm using 5.4 :)

Answer (score 1):

Array dereferencing was made available in PHP 5.4. So you will need an extra step to get your value:

Change:

```
while($tab[array_keys($tab)[$a]] > 0)
```

to

```
$var = array_keys($tab);
while($tab[$var[$a]] > 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks for very fast reply :) What should I do now ? Is there other way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Don't use PHP 5.2. It's no longer supported. PHP 5.3 support will expire this spring. Use PHP 5.4 or PHP 5.5

Comment: I know, but I take part in competition. They have online compiler and only PHP 5.2 :) I'm using 5.4 :)

Comment: @JohnConde, it doesn't work. I have the same error.

Comment: Can you show your new code?

Comment: @JohnCode, It works great. I forgot edit my code e.g. "echo array_keys($tab)[$a];"